# Союз "и" + дееприч. оборот в начале предложения

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Добрый день! Следует ли отделять деепричастный оборот в начале предложения?
И, отдавая своего мальчика в это учебное заведение, в первую очередь нужно знать...

Answer (score 4):

Присоединительные союзы обычно относятся к предложению и  **отделяются от деепричастных оборотов**  запятой (особые правила только для союза А): 
**И, отдавая своего мальчика в это учебное заведение,** в первую очередь нужно знать...

Розенталь,  § 20. Обособленные обстоятельства

2. Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения): Наш отец  был из кантонистов, но, выслужив офицерский чин, оставил нам потомственное дворянство (Ч.); **То же после присоединительного союза, которым начинается предложение (союз стоит после точки**): **Но, рассмотрев всесторонне своё положение в роли мужа Вареньки**, он засмеялся (М. Т.); **И, подойдя ко мне**, сказал…

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от того, включаете ли вы И в деепричастный оборот или нет. Как у вас звучала бы фраза без оборота?
*И в первую очередь нужно знать...* или *В первую очередь нужно знать*?

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе говорится о **союзе** "и". В этом случае "и" как союз относится к основной части предложения и деепричастный оборот отделяется от него запятой (подробно в ответе @Sibylla).

**И, отдавая своего мальчика в это учебное заведение, в первую очередь нужно знать...**

Но возможно, автор вопроса не учла, что "и" может служить **усилительной частицей** (в данном примере "и" может быть заменено на "даже"). Тогда "и" как усилительная частица относится к обороту и не отделяется от него запятой.

**И (=даже) отдавая своего мальчика в это учебное заведение, в первую очередь нужно знать...**

Постановка запятой меняет смысл предложения.