# Пунктуация. Предлоги "невзирая на", "несмотря на"

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая после союза "но", "и" в начале предложения, когда за ним следуют предлоги "несмотря на", "невзирая на"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая ставится, в какой бы части предложения предлоги ни располагались.

[Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm) говорит об общем принципе:

> Как правило, обособляется оборот с предложным сочетанием *несмотря
>   на,* например: *Каждую летнюю зорю Герасим, несмотря на слепоту, ходил
>   в поле ловить перепелов* (Бунин). Но при тесной смысловой связи со
>   словом, после которого находится этот оборот, не обособляется и он,
>   например: *Пришел администратор, вызванный несмотря на поздний час.*

Справочная Грамоты.ру даёт ответ:

**[Вопрос № 275145](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=275145)**

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после союза но: Но невзирая
>   на сложности, им удалось сохранить семейные обряды и традиции.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Запятая после *но* нужна.
>
> ---

**Вопрос № 294355**

> Что такое оборот "Но несмотря на"? Но несмотря на все уговоры, Катя
>   решила бросить университет. Нужна ли запятая после НО?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Это союз *но* и предлог *несмотря на*. Верно: *Но, несмотря на все
>   уговоры, Катя решила бросить университет.*
>
> ---

**Вопрос № 224704**

> Правильно ли расставлены запятые? Но несмотря на многообразие средств
>   защиты, необходимо учитывать и многофункциональность и экономическую
>   рентабельность.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> После *но* лучше поставить запятую.

**Вопрос № 211008**

> В предложении: "Я лег около костра, но, несмотря на усталость, не мог
>   уснуть" - союз "но" надо выделять запятыми с обеих сторон?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Перед НО запятая нужна, а конструкция с *несмотря на* выделяется
>   факультативно в зависимости от смысла: *Я лег около костра, но,
>   несмотря на усталость, не мог уснуть* и *Я лег около костра, но
>   несмотря на усталость не мог уснуть*.

**[источник](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0)**

Comment: А если после "но", "и" в начале предложения следуют ДчО, деепричастия, то тоже выделяются запятыми с обеих сторон?

Comment: Есть ряд оговорок. *И,* например, может быть  усилительной частицей: *И прогуливая, он умудрялся не получать плохих оценок.* Частицы *только, лишь* в начале предложения тоже отменяют запятую. *Лишь выучив таблицу умножения, можно...* Особое внимание союзу *а*! http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113 См. также здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430464/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!