# Выделение "несмотря на <…>" запятыми

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, предлоги, запятые, деепричастия

1. То есть конструкция "несмотря на" + дополнение (как член предложения) выделяется запятой по такой же аналогии, как деепричастный оборот, где деепричастие "смотря"? Например, в "Водитель, несмотря на дождь, смог увидеть сквозь стёкла" стоят запятые лишь потому, что слово "несмотря" произошло от деепричастия? А бывают исключения, чтобы не выделялось запятыми/запятой?

Answer (score 3):

Из ответа @Galina Avanesova ([Пунктуация. Предлоги "невзирая на", "несмотря на"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434462/%d0%9f%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0)):

[Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm) говорит об общем принципе:

> Как правило, обособляется оборот с предложным сочетанием *несмотря на*, например: Каждую летнюю зорю Герасим, несмотря на слепоту, ходил в поле ловить перепелов (Бунин). Но при тесной смысловой связи со словом, после которого находится этот оборот, не обособляется и он, например: *Пришел администратор, вызванный несмотря на поздний час.*

Answer (score 0):

Оборот с производным предлогом **несмотря на**, имеющим уступительное значение  **вопреки**, обособляется всегда (чаще, если стоит перед сказуемым, тогда ярче подчёркивается добавочное лексическое значение). Кроме того, его можно по смыслу заменить сочетанием **независимо от**
Например, *несмотря на жесточайший мороз, они  отправились в путь*.
Оборот с производным предлогом **несмотря на**, стоящим сразу после сказуемого или входящий в состав данного  составного именного сказуемого,  не будет выделяться запятыми,  поскольку смысловая нагрузка объединяет его со сказуемым, находящимся с ним в непосредственной близости.
Например, *они   продолжали стоять несмотря на ливень*.
**Несмотря (на)**  -  это действительно отглагольный производный предлог, и он тоже всегда обособляется на письме, но не потому, что слово произошло от деепричастия, а потому что оборот имеет обстоятельственное добавочное уступительное значение.