# Всё хорошо. Но(,) несмотря на это, что-то плохо

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны запятые?

`Всё было тип-топ, но(,) несмотря на это, я чувствовал себя не как дома.`

`Всё хорошо. Но(,) несмотря на это, что-то плохо.`

Comment: во втором точка выглядит неоправданной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Всё было тип-топ, но, несмотря на это, я чувствовал себя не как дома.***

***Всё хорошо. Но, несмотря на это, что-то плохо.***

Запятая ставится, т. к. оборот можно убрать или переставить без потери стуктуры:

*Всё было тип-топ, но я чувствовал себя не как дома*;

*Всё хорошо. Но что-то плохо*;

*Всё было тип-топ, но я чувствовал себя не как дома, **несмотря на это***;

*Всё хорошо. Но что-то плохо, **несмотря на это***.

Comment: Максим, вы часто пользуетесь этим правилом, а почему? Я называю его ТЕХНИЧЕСКИМ ПРИЕМОМ для некоторых случаев, а вы универсальным средством для решения всех задач. Вы не могли бы дать мне ссылку на него.  Он используется в СПП с двойными союзами ЕСЛИ...ТО, а еще где?

Comment: @Sharon Лучше вы дайте мне ссылку, чтоб я знал, почему ВЫ не отделяете. Это в люьом случае так: если можно «оторвать» и переставить, то от союзов отделяется запятой. Я вашу логику не понимаю. Лучше вы дайте мне ссылку на правило, о том, где не отделять принято.

Comment: У меня появилась идея: вам надо "пожаловаться" на меня на форуме. Другими словами, спросить про правило перестановки: когда и зачем  его МОЖНО или НУЖНО применять (разница есть). В чем смысл вашего "универсального ключика", которым вы все двери хотите открыть?  Я лучше там вам отвечу.

Comment: А вы капризны, сэр. Я выполняю все ваши желания на тему ссылок, как будто я джин из бутылки. Почему все должно быть так, как ЛУЧШЕ вам?))

Comment: @Sharon Где капризы? Я все в ответе написал, объяснение дал. А вот почему вы не ставите — не знаю. Я хочу узнать, почему вы не ставите. Почему так, как лучше МНЕ? Неправда, я ссылку прошу уже сказал почему. Так я, наоборот, пойму вашу точку зрения, научусь понимать вас, почему вы думаете, что союзы входят в состав обстоятельственных оборотов.

Comment: Максим, what's the problem?  This is your answer field, isn't it?  И я хотела уточнить, в чем вы видите смысл вашего универсального правила перестановки. Вы собираетесь ТАК решать все задачи?  Is this really true?

Comment: И еще вопрос, вот предложение:  Всё хорошо. Но(,) вопреки этому , что-то все равно плохо.  Как выбрать и объяснить запятую?  Извините за вопросы-расспросы, просто хочется понять тему)

Comment: @Sharon Запятая нужна, так как, опять же, можно «оторвать и переставить: ___Но что-то всë равно плохо, вопреки этому___. Так говорится о деепричастном обороте. Можно сделать по аналогии с другими оборотами и вводными словами, почему нет? И почему вы всë же считаете запятую ненужной?)

Comment: Метод перестановки говорит о самостоятельности элемента, но это все. Вариативности решения он не исключается, оба варианта возможны. Вот чем плох этот прием. Надо учитывать другие факторы.  Что касается НЕСМОТРЯ НА, то я соглашусь с запятой, если ее хотя бы как-то объяснят.  Где-нибудь можно найти объяснение? Или это просто ВОЛЕВОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ, как я подозреваю? Тогда пусть честно об этом напишут. Как бы это особый подход ко всему, что касается "несмотря на", Такая у него привилегия ввиду его глагольной формы.

Comment: @Sharon Я просто спрашиваю, почему вы считаете ненужной запятую, и прошу пока источник. Вы постоянно уходите от этого.

Comment: И вы мне это говорите?!))  Да вы на каждый мой вопрос не отвечаете, а задаете свой вопрос. Я тоже прошу у вас источник, как вы заметили. Метод перестановки меня не устраивает.  Я решила задачу другим способом, но мне дают  ссылку на Грамоту.  Почему я не могу решить своим способом, а вы можете? Есть правило, регулирующее отнесенность подчинительного союза к обстоятельственному обороту? Я не знаю такого правила. В текстах  пишут по-разному. Свое решение я обосновало. Теперь ваш ход.

Comment: Я своë тоже обосновал. Можно ещë и вот это для примера привести: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434462/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Я напишу так:

*Всё было тип-тОп, **но несмотря на Это,** я чувствовал себя не как дОма.*

*Всё хорошо. **Но несмотря на Это**, что-то плОхо.*

**Пояснение**

Я не вижу необходимости **отделять союз** **НО** от оборота: **по смыслу** противительный союз  и оборот со значением уступки **дополняют** друг друга. Также они составляют одну **фонетическую фразу** небольшого объема, которую  **нежелательно** делить на части.

**Примеры:**

***Но несмотря на это,** маленький ослик гордо расхаживал по городу с высоко поднятой головой, и поступь его была величавой и твёрдой.* Гунхильд Селин, Маленький ослик Марии. Бегство в Египет, 1962.

*Само собою разумеется, что бабушка объяснила ему свое мнение насчет телесного наказания, и он не смел бить нас; **но несмотря на это**, он часто угрожал, в особенности мне, розгами..*. Л. Н. Толстой. Отрочество (1854)

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9D%D0%BE%2C+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Зачем тогда спрашиваете, если можете найти ответ на Грамоте? Отсутствие запятой допускается после НО, например, перед придаточными или вводными. Почему бы это не применить к обороту с "несмотря на" в силу интонации?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр  А на какое правило ссылается Грамота, как вы думаете? А то похоже на ответ Дельфийского оракула.  Мне бы что-нибудь из ПАС или Розенталя, они все-таки обосновывают свое мнение, знания сведены в  систему. А это решение  мне неизвестно. Привяжите его хотя бы к чему-нибудь.